# How to align drop-down display in a QGIS dock plugin

Tags: qgis, qt, dropdownlist

I have made a QGIS plugin using the dockwidget display mode. The GUI is made with Qt Designer. It contains a few dropdowns, one of them for layer selection.

It's working really well, but when the layer name is really long, the drop down menu showing the layer's name is misaligned and hides a few millimetres on the right. How can I fix this? Maybe by adding some padding around the right side?

In the example below, it should read epsg28355 at the end, it's missing a '5' at the edge of the screen.

[image: screenshot]